# How to use volley library for network call using Socket(IP address) and port number(eg. 1234)?

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask, android-volley

I want to send byte [] to make a request and in the response i will get the byte[].So can you please help me.

Right now i am using the Asynctask doInBackground() for the network call and Socket class.

Had gone through some link but could not found the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems Volley is a *http* library, see [this](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html?hl=pt-br). It's good enough to use `AsyncTask` for this.

**Edit**

> [Kryonet](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet) is another very good Java network library for sending TCP and
>   UDP packets over network efficiently which runs on Android as well.
>   Though whenever I used Kryonet, I wrote both the server side code and
>   client side code using this library. Kryonet keeps the connection
>   alive though, so if you don't have any issues changing your server
>   side code from Python to Java (Kryonet has samples which you can use),
>   then it will serve your purpose well. Using this library, you don't
>   even need to hardcode any IP address. You can discover the local
>   server in real time with just one line of code.

Quoted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21941312/is-there-any-library-to-manage-tcp-packets-on-android)

Comment: But i want to handle the call of the request using the request queue.Can you suggest any other library for the same